# Unable to compile groovy script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

The script is working fine in groovy console. But when I do check-syntax for the same script in Jenkins, the following error message is coming up -

```
Script1.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
@ line 6, column 1.
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
^
Script1.groovy: 4: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.ContentType
@ line 4, column 1.
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
^
Script1.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
@ line 3, column 1.
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder....
```

How to get this issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This exception is because you dont have these dependencies (Jars) that has these classes so you have two option :
1- if you currently using any dependency management framework like (maven,gradle) then just add these dependencies 
2- in the groovy file at the top add @Grapes and then add the dependency here an example :

```
    @Grapes(
        @Grab(group='yourDependencyGroupID', module='yourDependencyArtifactID'
                                           , version='theDesireVersion')
    )
```

you can search for these dependencies in [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com)

i hope this will help :)